# vba hyperlinks to copy data from html files

Tags: vba, hyperlink

i have a problem here,I have an excel file which has id column,all ids are hyperlinked to html files,now i have to get the user address from the html file and display it against the ids in the excel file,the html file names are random so i dont know what to do..can someone help?..thanks!

i dono what logic to use,

first excel file

id address

---

1

---

2

---

this id column is hyperlinked to a file location which has html files
How can we search for the files which have random names?

Comment: [**Here**](http://www.bohack.com/2009/06/get-the-url-from-a-hyperlink-in-excel/) have a look at this....

Comment: Thanks a lot mate @Vasim..its works!

Comment: Can you please upvote my comment then...Glad I was able to help...

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity added the answer from Vasim's link from the questions comments

```
Function GETURL(HyperlinkCell As Range)
   GETURL = HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

[Get url from hyperlink in excel](http://www.bohack.com/2009/06/get-the-url-from-a-hyperlink-in-excel/)